# Maintain consistent font size in landscape/portrait

Tags: css, mobile, responsive-design

I have the below code in my css file:

```
body {
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
    -moz-text-size-adjust: none;
    -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
    font:  normal 75% 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}
```

When I look at my website in portrait, it's fine.  But then as soon as I rotate into landscape, my font scales up to the increased size.  I want the font to remain completely as it is.  The above code seems to have fixed the issue for many other people, but as you can see from my screenshots, the font is clearly larger in landscape when compared to portrait.

Screenshots below:

[Portrait](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L7Wot.png)

[Landscape](https://i.stack.imgur.com/USGx0.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it wasn't strictly an issue with the font...it was a viewport issue:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try splitting up your css font into:

```
font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
font-size: 1.5em;
```

Check out the [font-size documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-size#Syntax) to see the difference between relative, percentage, and length values.